# Bitwise & Operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I don't understand why only num1 would print output when they both should be. Am I missing something here?

```js
var num1 = 0x200127;
var num2 = 0x200124;
    
if(num1 & 0x100 == 0x100){
    console.log("num1: " + (num1 & 0x100 ) );
}
if(num2 & 0x100 == 0x100){
    console.log("num2: " + (num2 & 0x100 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an issue with order of operations.
For reference, check the [table of JavaScript operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence#Table).

`==` has a precidence of 10 while `&` has a precidence of 9, so `==` gets evaluated first.

So your code is essentially evaluating:

```
num & (0x100 == 0x100)
```

Which is equivalent to:

```
num & true
```

`num1` is outputted while `num2` is not because:

```
0x200127 & true == 1 (true)
0x200124 & true == 0 (false)
```

Try putting your bitwise operations in parenthesis, as the [grouping operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Grouping) has the highest precedence of all.

```
if((num1 & 0x100) == 0x100){
    console.log("num1: " + (num1 & 0x100 ) );
}
if((num2 & 0x100) == 0x100){
    console.log("num2: " + (num2 & 0x100 ) );
}
```

Test it below:

```js
var num1 = 0x200127,
  num2 = 0x200124,
  output = document.getElementById('output');

if ((num1 & 0x100) == 0x100) {
  output.innerHTML += "<p>num1: " + (num1 & 0x100) + "</p>";
}
if ((num2 & 0x100) == 0x100) {
  output.innerHTML += "<p>num2: " + (num2 & 0x100) + "</p>";
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `==` operator has a [**higher precedence**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) than `&`. So

```
x & y == z
```

is evaluated as

```
x & (y == z)
```

In the second case, that makes the condition evaluated to `0` and thus `false`:

```
num2 & 0x100 == 0x100
0x200124 & 0x100 == 0x100
0x200124 & true
0x200124 & 1
0
```

You want to change the precedence by using the grouping operator:

```
if((num1 & 0x100) == 0x100){
    console.log("num1: " + (num1 & 0x100 ) );
}
if((num2 & 0x100) == 0x100){
    console.log("num2: " + (num2 & 0x100 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, I guess that == has a higher precedence than the & operator. if I change the code to this, it works.

```js
var num1 = 0x200127;
var num2 = 0x200124;
    
if(num1 & 0x100 == 0x100){
    console.log("num1: " + (num1 & 0x100 ) );
}
if((num2 & 0x100) == 0x100){
    console.log("num2: " + (num2 & 0x100 ) );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript == has higer precedence order then bitwise AND operator thus on comparison of `0x100 == 0x100 always result in 1` that is true, and

```
if we do Bitwise AND of 1 with even number, result will always be 0. 
And if we do Bitwise AND of 1 with odd number, result will always be 1
```

.